# How to fix conflicts with imported type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm just creating a web application and I stuck with the problem. What is the correct way to inporting types? This is my classes into App_Data folder. Actually, all properties of my classes were changed like this: Build Action - Content (moved to Compile).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace sample.App_Code.HistoricalStock
{
    public class HistoricalStock
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Open { get; set; }
        public double High { get; set; }
        public double Low { get; set; }
        public double Close { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public double AdjClose { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using sample.App_Code.HistoricalStock;

namespace sample.App_Code.HistoricalStockDownload
{
    public class HistoricalStockDownloader
    {
        public static List<HistoricalStock> DownloadData(string ticker, int yearToStartFrom)
        {
            List<HistoricalStock> retval = new List<HistoricalStock>();

            // some code 

            return retval;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get your problem but it is not a good idea to have a type and namespace part with identical name.

- your namespace: `sample.App_Code.HistoricalStock`
- your class: `HistoricalStock`

Because when you try to use `List<HistoricalStock>` in the `HistoricalStockDownloader` class it may not even be compiled.